# Type mismatch error when using extensions in Scala 3.3

Tags: scala, scala-3

When compiling the following code:

```
enum Tree[+A]:
    case Leaf(value: A)
    case Branch(left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A])

    extension (t: Tree[Int]) def firstPositive: Int = t match
        case Leaf(i) => i
        case Branch(l, r) =>
            val lpos = l.firstPositive
            if lpos > 0 then lpos else r.firstPositive
```

I get these errors:

```
-- [E008] Not Found Error: -----------------------------------------------------
137 |            if lpos > 0 then lpos else r.firstPositive
    |               ^^^^^^
    |value > is not a member of Tree[Int] => Int, but could be made available as an extension method.
    |
    |One of the following imports might make progress towards fixing the problem:
    |
    |  import math.Ordered.orderingToOrdered
    |  import math.Ordering.Implicits.infixOrderingOps
    |
-- [E007] Type Mismatch Error: -------------------------------------------------
137 |            if lpos > 0 then lpos else r.firstPositive
    |                             ^^^^
    |                             Found:    (lpos : Tree[Int] => Int)
    |                             Required: Int
    |
    | longer explanation available when compiling with `-explain`
-- [E007] Type Mismatch Error: -------------------------------------------------
137 |            if lpos > 0 then lpos else r.firstPositive
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                                       Found:    Tree[Int] => Int
    |                                       Required: Int
    |
    | longer explanation available when compiling with `-explain`
3 errors found
```

It looks like `l.firstPositive` has type `Tree[Int] => Int` and not `Int`. One workaround is to write `l.firstPositive(l)`, but then there's no point in using extensions. What am I doing wrong?

Btw, this code snippet is copied from [Functional Programming in Scala Second Edition](https://books.google.pl/books/about/Functional_Programming_in_Scala_Second_E.html?id=JaO9EAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) (page 52), which is a very recent book.

Comment: What if you declare the method as ` def firstPositive()`? I was actually thinking it was mandatory in Scala 3.

Comment: @GaëlJ I don't think so, the following method works just fine: `def size: Int = this match case Leaf(_) => 1 case Branch(l, r) => 1 + l.size + r.size`

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug then. You might want to open an issue on Scala's GitHub. Declaration with parenthesis is a simple workaround anyway.

Comment: @GaëlJ Based on Scala docs, `Extension methods let you add methods to a type after the type is defined`. This particular example is defining an extension method within the type definition. IMHO, being able to define such thing is a bug, this should've been a compile-time error.

Comment: Right, I hadn't even noticed it was defined in the same type!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't seem to be a bug, one of the things that I think might be confusing in Scala3 is the indentation rules, that might be misleading in some cases. I haven't read the book yet, but I have a feeling that either you haven't followed the indentations correctly, or it's some mistake in the book. In your case, you're defining an extension method over a specific implementation of `Tree`, namely `Tree[Int]`, which should be outside the scope of the `Tree` enum itself. This works perfectly fine:

```
enum Tree[+A]:
  case Leaf(value: A)
  case Branch(left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A])

import Tree.*

// the same indentation as Tree definition, meaning it's outside the scope
extension (t: Tree[Int]) def firstPositive: Int = 
  t match
    case Leaf(i) => i
    case Branch(l, r) =>
        val lpos = l.firstPositive
        if lpos > 0 then lpos else r.firstPositive
```

## TL;DR

### My assumptions on why this is happening (not sure about it)

One thing to note here is that when you define the extension method inside the `Tree`, by the definition of a method, it's first argument (the actual instance) is passed to it implicitly:

```
enum Tree[+T]:
   // sum types here
   extension (t: Tree[Int]) def whatever: Int = ???
```

Would be expanded to something like this (not precisely) when you put the extension inside the scope of `Tree`:

```
def whetever(this: Tree[_])(t: Tree[Int]): Int = ???
```

That might be the reason why `lpos` is being detected as a function from `Tree[Int]` to `Int`. In fact you can write something like this:

```
enum Tree[+A]:
  case Leaf(value: A)
  case Branch(left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A])


  extension (t: Tree[Int]) def firstPositive: Int = 
    t match
      case Leaf(i) => i
      case Branch(l, r) =>
          // first l is "this", latter one is "t"
          val lpos = l.firstPositive(l)
          if lpos > 0 then lpos else r.firstPositive(r)
```

If my assumptions are correct, I can't see why defining such thing, which is both a method and an extension method at the same time is not a specific compile-time error.

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact, the book does not specify how to indent this piece of code. It was my mistake to assume that it should be inside the class.